# How to rename an AWS IoT Rule?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I have made an IoT rule in AWS IoT. I need to change the rule name. I have tried to click on the 3 dots in the right corner of the rule *(shown below)*. It has no such option. 
[image: Clicked The Right Corner of The Rule]

And clicking on that rule gives a summary of the rule. However, it does not provide a way to change the rule name. It only gives an option to change the description.

Comment: Looks like it's not possible without deleting and re-adding it.

Comment: @Spiff yeah. It is not a convenient way.

Answer (score 1):

IoT Rules, like most things in the service, can't be renamed and have to be deleted and added again instead. The exception I believe is Things themselves, which can have their names updated via the CLI.